# Excel VBA Changing Website Combobox

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I have a webpage I'm trying to interact with.  It has a parent combobox titled "Result".  When Result is set to the option at Index 2 it pops up a child combobox with two options.  Setting the index of the parent combobox and firing the onchange event works perfectly.

However nothing I do has succeeded at manipulating the child combobox in the way I'm looking for.

This is the webpage code for the child combobox:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="SAVE PENDINGDIV" >
<select name="SAVE PENDINGSelect" class="famSelect" style="width:10em" onChange="handleSys(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="" selected="selected" >Text 1</option>
<option value="Y">Text 2</option>
```

Here is my code down to manipulating the parent combobox:

```
Set objshell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

IE_Count = objshell.Windows.count

For x = 0 To (IE_Count - 1)

    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_URL = objshell.Windows(x).document.Location
    my_title = objshell.Windows(x).document.Title

    'find the desired page
    If my_title Like "Page Title" Then

        Set ie = objshell.Windows(x)
        Exit For

    End If

Next

ie.document.getelementbyid("Result").selectedIndex = 2
ie.document.getelementbyid("Result").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

I've tried getelementbyname and getelementbyid.  Here is a rundown of things I've tried with no success:

```
ie.document.getelementbyid("SAVE PENDINGDIV").Value = "Text 2"
ie.document.getelementbyid("SAVE PENDINGDIV").Focus
ie.document.getelementbyid("SAVE PENDINGDIV").FireEvent ("onchange")

ie.document.getelementbyid("SAVE PENDINGDIV").Selected = "Selected"
ie.document.getelementbyid("SAVE PENDINGDIV").Click

ie.document.getelementbyid("SAVE PENDINGDIV").selectedIndex = 1
ie.document.getelementbyid("SAVE PENDINGDIV").options.selectedIndex = 1
```

I've only gotten one thing to kind of work:

```
ie.document.getelementbyid("SAVE PENDINGDIV").innerText = "Text 2"
```

This gets rid of the combobox, which I'm not trying to do, and replaces it with "Text 2" as plain text.